# Loop through using index that are in no order in Matlab

Tags: matlab, foreach

I'm not sure how to formulate my question so let me just show you. Say I have a function `func` that takes in a set of parameters `p1,p2,p3,p4` and returns one single number `number`. I want to vary only `p1` and see how my `number` varies with varying `p1`. What I did was this:

```
iterations = 100;
result = zeros(1,iterations);

for p1 = 1:iterations
     result(1,p1) = func(p1,1,2,3)
end 

plot(1:100,result);
```

**Question:** Say for example I want to only try for `p1_vector = [0.3, 0.6, 4, 7, 10, 11, 11.2, 13, ...etc]` and so on. How can loop through using an index `i` that only takes values from the vector `p1_vector`?

I hope I've made this question clear, I'm sorry if any confusions till exists, please let me know how I can improve. I did some searches before I posted this but I only got "`for each`" results but on different languages.

Comment: Use a loop `for ii=1:numel(p1_vector)`, then use `p1= p1_vector(ii)`. Index into your output array using `ii`, not `p1`.

Comment: You might also want to plot the results against `p1` using `plot(p1,result)` to see the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cris commented, you can loop through the index itself and use that index to access the vector values:

```matlab
> p1_vector = [0.3, 0.6, 4, 7, 10, 11, 11.2, 13];
> for index = 1:length(p1_vector)
    value = p1_vector(index)
  end

value = 0.3000
value = 0.6000
value = 4
value = 7
value = 10
value = 11
value = 11.200
value = 13
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is a feature only available for newer versions of Matlab, but you can loop through the values directly: `for value = p1_vector; display(value); end;`